# How to remove files that start with 2011XXXX

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, rm

I have a bunch of files i need to delete, they all start with 2011XXXX. How would i delete them. So far i have this command:

```
ls | grep 2011 | xargs rm
```

And it works, but is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the files are all in the current folder, how about just `rm 2011*`? :)

Comment: … unless that — given that we are nearing the end of 2011 — causes `ARG_MAX`, or [related limits](http://www.in-ulm.de./~mascheck/various/argmax/#maximum_number), to be exceeded. ☺